# Cannot change color of glyphicon

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have span of glyphicon

Here is code

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar blue" style="color: #1d69b4;background:transparent;border:none;"></span>
```

On my local machine I have it blue color

[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpaJT.png)

But on server I have this

[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QH6X.png)

Why so and how I can make it same color like on local server?

Comment: That is not the same image, the icon is different on the server.

Comment: But code is same! @the4kman

Comment: Look in Dev tools and make sure the glyphicon are being loaded.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff


Have this@AlexThomas

Comment: So okay. I solve error that I see in dev console. But I didn't solve main error@AlexThomas

Comment: What version of IIS is running on your production server?  You might be missing the MIME types for .woff .woff2 font files which would prevent it serving up the file.    They look like different icons in your screenshots - are you sure the correct .woff files have been deployed?

Comment: I added manually woff types to web.config @83N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens with me many times, after deleting caches and cookies it works fine. you can try it. or try it on different browser/system.

Answer (score 0):

Another css is overwriting your style do it this way:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar blue" style="color: #1d69b4 !important;background:transparent;border:none;"></span>
```